# How to install Calendar-Indicator in Ubuntu 15.10?

Tags: unity, indicator, calendar

I followed the following steps to install [Calendar-Indicator](http://www.webupd8.org/2012/02/calendar-indicator-displays-google.html):

1. `add-apt-repository ppa:atareao/atareao`
2. `apt-get update`
3. `apt-get install calendar-indicator`

It successfully installed but I cannot find the application in the Unity Dash, neither access it from the command line:

```
orschiro@x230:~$ cal
cal            calendar       calibrate_ppa  caller
```

Comment: It should have installed a `.desktop` file, named: `extras-calendar-indicator.desktop` , with inside the command: `/opt/extras.ubuntu.com/calendar-indicator/bin/calendar-indicator`. Isn't that the case?

Comment: I'm sorry for my late response. Indeed, this is the solution. The icon was present after restart. :)